# Unexpected token error R subset

Tags: r

Im using Rstudio and I can't seem to solve this problem: 
I have a df which I want to subset by taking only some columns and so I do the following:

```
dfo <- read.csv("cwurData.csv")
df<- subset(dfo, c=("world_rank", "country", "quality_of_education", 
"alumni_employment", "publications", "patents", "year"))
```

To which I get the following error: (and I can't see why!)

```
Error: unexpected ',' in "df<- subset(dfo, c=("world_rank","
```

Thanks for your help:)

Comment: no `=` after `c`

Answer (score 1):

I am assuming that all the quoted names are names of columns you want to select, if so the problem is that you are not using the select argument in the subset function (see ?subset for details). An example of how to use this function on the diamonds data set from ggplot2 can be seen below:

```
install.packages('ggplot2')

library(ggplot2)

diamonds

subset_d= subset(diamonds,select=c('cut','color'))
```

Also just some other things to note, you look like your attempting to assign a vector of character values to c by doing c=('x','y','z',...), just a reminder that you need to instead do c=**c**('x','y','z',...), the c before the parentheses being a combine function call. Good practice would also be to assign vectors to variable names other than 'c', as this causes confusion with the function name. Let me know of any other questions.

Comment: the error is due to the OP sticking an `=` where it doesn't belong